# How to find successor for a given node BST

Tags: java, methods, binary-search-tree, inorder

I am trying to build an algorithm to find a node's successor, by recursively calling the following :

```
 public static BTreeNode inorderFirst(BTree T) {

    BTreeNode n = T.getRoot();
    if (n == null)
        return null;
    while (n.getLeftChild() != null)
        n = n.getLeftChild();
    return n;

}
```

And calling this

```
public static BTreeNode inorderNext(BTreeNode n) {

    //returns successor. if it finds one.

    // TODO

    // if node has a right child get its left descendant.

     // otherwise get the first ancestor of which in the left sub-tree the node n is.

     // if it didn't find
    return null;

} // inorderNext()
```

I am using custom imports which have methods for getting `getLeftChild()`, and so on also has `getParent()` which aren't too hard to figure out. If anyone has any ideas on how to start building this. I have added some comments of my own plan. I just don't know how to start executing. I would like the structure because it makes it easier to test the method.
I figured out a way to make it work without using the recursion:

```
   public static BTreeNode inorderNext(BTreeNode n) {


   if (n.getRightChild() != null) {
    BTreeNode temp = n.getRightChild();
    while (temp.getLeftChild() != null)
        temp = temp.getLeftChild();
    return temp;
   }

   else {
    BTreeNode temp = n;
    BTreeNode par = n.getParent();
    while (par != null) {
        if (par.getLeftChild() == temp)
        return par;
        else {
        temp = par;
        par = par.getParent();
        }
    }

    }

    return null;

} // inorderNext()
```

But i am still wondering if there was a way to use the first function recursively on this one.

Answer (score 0):

Your code would be something like the following:

```
if(n.getLeftChild() != null)
        inorderNext(n.getLeftChild());
    System.out.print(n.data);
    if(n.getRightChild() != null)
        inorderNext(n.getRightChild());
```

Comment: I am supposed to use inorderFirst recursively to complete the task of getting a successor and returning it.

Comment: Does your inorderFirst have to take a tree? It would make sense for it to take a particular node and the inOrder take the tree.

Comment: I am not supposed to change the methods in any way shape or form.

Comment: I did find a way to do it without recursion still wondering if there was a way to use it in there.

Comment: In this situation I don’t think recursion will work. It doesn’t make sense, atleast to me.